# arc, strong and weak instance variables

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Just trying to fully understand ARC.

```
MyView *testView = [[MyView alloc] init];

__weak MyView *weakView = testView;

[weakView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"alpha" options:0 context:nil];

testView = nil;

if(weakView) {
     NSLog(@"WeakView exists!");
}
```

I don't understand why my NSLog statement is printing. Since weakView is a weak reference to testView, shouldn't it be pointing to nil once testView is set to nil???

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `addObserver` method seems to `retain` and `autorelease` the view. Thats why the weak reference is not zeroed right after the initial reference is nilled. Just run this code in the debugger:

```
UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] init];

__weak UIView *weakView = testView;

@autoreleasepool {
    [weakView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"alpha" options:0 context:nil];
}

testView = nil;

if(weakView) {
    NSLog(@"WeakView exists!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may or may not. It goes to nil when the object is deallocated. The fact that you set `testView` to nil only implies that you are releasing the object. But the object is not guaranteed to immediately be deallocated.

The problem here is that you are assuming a given value for the retain count. You think that the alloc+init sequence gave you an object with a count of 1 so that when you set `testView` to nil it goes to 0 and the object is deallocated.

You should **never** assume a given retain count. You should always think in terms of relative retain counts. The alloc+init sequence returns a +1 object (not 1 but +1). When you set set `testView` to nil ARC calls `release` and turns it to a +0 object (not 0, but +0). This means you have no guarantee that it's still accessible. Your weak reference may or may not be valid.

What is in fact happening is that internally in the init method (or the chained init methods of the parents) there has been a call to `autorelease` therefore your object does not yet have a refcount of 0. It will get it (and be deallocated) at the next pool drain.

Edit:

Also what Adam says in his reply is correct.

Comment: `init` method does not send `autorelease` to the object. It creates the object with retain count = 1. It's the same with or without ARC.

Comment: Some init methods do, others do not. There are init methods that return an object that has infinite retain count. There are init methods that return an object that is **not** the object you allocated. You should **never** rely on an init method to return an object with a count of exactly 1 (or ANY method at all. In fact not even alloc should be considered to return an object that is guaranteed to have a retain count of 1).

Comment: The [basic rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) is: You own any object you create using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”. That means that you have to `release` or `autorelease` it when you are done with it. The retain count of 1 is not guaranteed, but it is at least 1 with these methods.

Comment: Exactly. It's common to refer to that using relative counts. The retain count is not 1, it is +1 meaning that you own the object and have to eventually release it, autorelease it or ... return it as a +1 object if you are one of those methods yourself. This, of course, implies that the actual count is at least 1, but it may be more.

Answer (score 0):

Your `testView` is local variable and local variables under ARC doesn't have precise lifetime semantics. Read 6.1 at:

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#optimization.precise

What does it mean? This means that the compiler can do whatever it wants to do.

Current implementation releases `testView` object at the end of the method. But what if the optimizer (now, future, ...) decides that the lifetime is over and it will release it sooner (before the end of the method)?

In other words, you're trying to depend on undefined behavior. Don't do this, don't rely on this. In this case, you never know when the object is really released = weak reference is zeroed.